# Complex regex text modifiaction

Tags: ios, regex, nsstring, nsregularexpression

Hi i have somehow a complex regex situation.

```
mainString = @"Main Term (Rounded) [Square] ~a~d~j~."
```

I need this to be returned like

```
modifiedString* = @"Main Term (Rounded) [Square] adj."
```

So every char after `~` must be italic or whatever attribute.
And I need the range for `"adj."` after modification so that I can add Attribtues.

Thank You.

```
NSError *error3 = nil;
    NSRegularExpression *SHRegex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\\~(.|)" options:0 error:&error3];
    NSArray *matches3 = [SHRegex matchesInString:mainString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [mainString length])];
    NSUInteger *numberOfMatches =  [SHRegex numberOfMatchesInString:mainString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, mainString.length)];

    NSString *modifiedString = [SHRegex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:mainString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length]) withTemplate:@""];
for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches3) {
        NSRange matchRange = [match range];
        NSRange firstHalfRange = [match rangeAtIndex:1];
        //NSRange secondHalfRange = [match rangeAtIndex:2];
        [string addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1] range:matchRange];
        //[string addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor blueColor] range:firstHalfRange];
    }
```

Comment: Just to clarify: do you want to remove all `~` characters from the string, and return the location of all characters that were surrounded by these characters? Is it always `~a~b~c~d~` or could it be `~abc~ d ~e~` - and in the latter case do you expect `abc d e` to be returned? And would ` d ` be part of the "special matched characters"? You had `~a~d~j~.` and wanted `adj.` to be "special". Does that mean you only need a tilde _before_ a special character?

Comment: it can be `Main ~a~d~j~. Sub ~a~d~v~.` and yes i want `~` deleted and the range or location of the remaining `adj.` and `adv.` returned. `Main` and `Sub` are not special.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code should do what you want. It creates an attributed string
where the tilde characters are removed, and an attribute is added to the
character following the tilde. I have added some comments which hopefully
explain how it works.

```
NSString *mainString = @"Main Term (Rounded) [Square] ~a~d~j~.";
NSMutableAttributedString *attrString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:mainString];

NSError *error = nil;
// Pattern that matches a tilde followed by an arbitrary character:
NSString *pattern = @"(\\~)(.)";
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern options:0 error:&error];

__block NSUInteger offset = 0;
[regex enumerateMatchesInString:mainString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [mainString length])
                     usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *result, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop) {
      NSRange firstHalfRange = [result rangeAtIndex:1];  // range of the tilde
      NSRange secondHalfRange = [result rangeAtIndex:2]; // range of the following character
      // Adjust locations according to the string modifications:
      firstHalfRange.location += offset;
      secondHalfRange.location += offset;
      // Set attribute for the character:
      [attrString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1] range:secondHalfRange];
      // Remove the tilde:
      [[attrString mutableString] deleteCharactersInRange:firstHalfRange];
      // Update offset:
      offset -= firstHalfRange.length;
}];
```

---

*Update* in response to your comment: The following code matches two patterns (tilde or caret followed by a character) and uses different attributes for the replacement.

```
NSString *mainString = @" ~a^b~c^d";
NSMutableAttributedString *attrString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:mainString];

NSError *error = nil;
NSString *pattern = @"(\\~|\\^)(.)";
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern options:0 error:&error];

__block NSUInteger offset = 0;
[regex enumerateMatchesInString:mainString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [mainString length])
                     usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *result, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop) {
     NSRange firstHalfRange = [result rangeAtIndex:1];
     NSRange secondHalfRange = [result rangeAtIndex:2];
     NSString *firstMatch = [mainString substringWithRange:firstHalfRange];
     // Adjust locations according to the string modifications:
     firstHalfRange.location += offset;
     secondHalfRange.location += offset;
     // Set color attribute for the character:
     if ([firstMatch isEqualToString:@"~"]) {
         [attrString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1] range:secondHalfRange];
     } else {
         [attrString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:1 blue:0 alpha:1] range:secondHalfRange];
     }
     [[attrString mutableString] deleteCharactersInRange:firstHalfRange];
     // Update offset:
     offset -= firstHalfRange.length;
}];
```

Comment: My database structure has a tilde before every character that's supposed to be subscript. which is now done thanks to you. But also i want every character following `^` to be superscript. adding the same code does the job but then if same entry had both variation its crashing as `indexOutOfRange`...any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

Does your regex implementation support positive lookbehind?

If so, you could use `(?<=~)(.)` to match `a`, `d`, `j` and `.` separately.